# Want an urdu title in shopify admin graphql query

Tags: graphql, internationalization, shopify-api

I want to support multiple languages:

```
{
  products(first:10,) {
    edges {
      node {
        title                
        # Include other fields to retrieve within translations
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the title response in Urdu. I am using admin/api/2023-07/graphql.json

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is done using the [@inContext](https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/building-with-the-storefront-api/markets/multiple-languages#step-2-retrieve-translations) decorator.

```
query getProducts @inContext(language: UR) {
  products(first:10)  {
    edges {
      node {
        title                
        # Include other fields to retrieve within translations
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @inContext(language: UR) is working in storefront APIS but its not working in admin graphql apis

Comment: I wonder if the Shopify Admin is not localizable?

Comment: maybe it is localizable by Shopify configuration but I don't know.Thanks